# How to Access Underlying Document of a new Notes Email Before it is Saved

Tags: java, plugins, lotus-notes

We have a Lotus Notes Plug-In, developed in Java. The current version of Notes we're supporting is 8.5.2.

This plug-in adds a button to the Notes UI. When the user clicks it, we present a window to the user, which allows the user to add the current item to our web-based application using web services. Everything works fine, except when the user tries to add a *new email item.*

The listener for the "click event" (if you will) needs to know the current document so that it can pass its field data to the web service call. In order to do that, a separate listener has been set up (`DocumentContextService`) which essentially gets invoked any time the input focus changes within the Notes UI.

`DocumentContextService` attempts to retrieve the URI of the current document. And that's where things fall apart. I am finding that an unsent email message *has no URI*. Further, there appears to be no way to get to the document and save it, so that I can obtain one.

Theoretically, this is by design. Oddly, I can see that the new document has a DocumentKey, so I know it exists (as a draft somewhere), but I cannot get to it. So there doesn't appear to be any way to access the document's data until it is actually saved.

Unless I'm wrong (and I very well could be). And there's the question: **Is there a way to obtain the underlying document of a new email before it has been saved so that I can access its data (specifically, its fields)?**

The code from the document context listener is below. The problem, again, is that the URI property always evaluates to an empty string for new emails.

```
package com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.internal;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;
import org.eclipse.ui.model.IWorkbenchAdapter;
import org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertyDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.IPropertySource;

import com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.document.IDocumentContext;
import com.ibm.rcp.jface.launcher.IURIProvider;
import com.satuit.sys.The;

/**
 * Extracts document information about about a selection object. Represents the document within the DocumentSelection.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class DocumentContext implements IDocumentContext
{
    private IWorkbenchPart part;
    private Object obj;
    private String label;
    private URI uri;
    private ImageDescriptor icon;
    private Properties properties;
    private String id;

    /**
     * Initializes a new instance of the DocumentContext class.
     * 
     * @param part  The current view part.
     * @param obj   The currently selected object.
     */
    public DocumentContext(final IWorkbenchPart part, final Object obj)
    {
        this.part = part;
        this.obj = obj;

        // Is this object a URIProvider?
        final IURIProvider provider = (IURIProvider)ContextUtil.getAdapterObject(obj, IURIProvider.class);
        if (provider != null)
        {
            this.uri = provider.getURI();
            this.label = provider.getTitle();
            this.icon = provider.getImageDescriptor();
        }

        if (this.label == null || this.icon == null)
        {
            // Is this object a workbench adapter?
            final IWorkbenchAdapter wba = (IWorkbenchAdapter)ContextUtil.getAdapterObject(obj, IWorkbenchAdapter.class);
            if (wba != null)
            {
                if (this.label != null)
                {
                    this.label = wba.getLabel(obj);
                }

                if (this.icon != null)
                {
                    this.icon = wba.getImageDescriptor(obj);
                }

            }

            if (this.icon == null)
            {
                final Image i = part.getTitleImage();
                if (i != null)
                {
                    this.icon = ImageDescriptor.createFromImage(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // Is this object a URI?
        if (this.uri == null)
        {
            this.uri = (URI)ContextUtil.getAdapterObject(obj, URI.class);
        }

        //  Is this object a PropertySource?
        //  (A document that isn't a URI provider may provide a URI in its properties.)
        final IPropertySource prop = (IPropertySource)ContextUtil.getAdapterObject(obj, IPropertySource.class);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            this.properties = buildProperties(prop);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the ID of this instance.
     * @return A string containing the ID.
     */
    public final String getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the workbench part used to initialize this instance.
     * @return
     */
    public final IWorkbenchPart getPart()
    {
        return this.part;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.document.IDocumentContext#getImageDescriptor()
     */
    public final ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor()
    {
        return this.icon;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.document.IDocumentContext#getLabel()
     */
    public final String getLabel()
    {
        if (this.label == null && this.part != null)
        {
            return this.part.getTitle();
        }

        return this.label;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.document.IDocumentContext#getObject()
     */
    public final Object getObject()
    {
        return this.obj;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.document.IDocumentContext#getProperties()
     */
    public final Properties getProperties()
    {
        return this.properties;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.ibm.lotuslabs.context.service.document.IDocumentContext#getURI()
     */
    public final URI getURI()
    {
        return this.uri;
    }

    private Properties buildProperties(final IPropertySource source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        final IPropertyDescriptor[] descs = source.getPropertyDescriptors();

        if (The.Value(null).Is.NullOrEmpty(descs))
        {
            return null;
        }

        final Properties prop = new Properties();
        for (int i = 0; i < descs.length; i++)
        {
            final Object id = descs[i].getId();
            final String name = descs[i].getDisplayName();

            String value = source.getPropertyValue(descs[i].getId()).toString();
            if (The.Value(descs[i].getDescription()).Is.Not.Null())
            {
                value += "|" + source.getPropertyValue(descs[i].getDescription()).toString();
            }

            if (this.uri == null)
            {
                if (The.Value("URI").Is.OneOfIgnoreCase(id.toString(), name) ||
                    The.Value("URL").Is.OneOfIgnoreCase(id.toString(), name))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.uri = new URI(value);
                        continue;
                    }
                    catch (URISyntaxException e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            prop.setProperty(name, value);
        }

        return prop;
    }

}
```

Comment: What uri you get for saved email? Does it contain universal ID (I think so)? If it does, you can't get URI for new document, because it does not exists... It *might* be similar to XP datasources - new document has UNID, but until saved it changes with every refresh and is useless to store it anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking. Oddly, our spec calls for an Add and Send button, but I don't see how they can expect to save the email from within the plugin because we don't have access to the email's data until it actually exists. And we can't control the sending at that particular stage. I'm thinking this is a No-Can-Do.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth, We do get a UNID for saved documents, btw. We get zilch for unsent emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, until the document is saved into the backend database, there is no document to get an URI for, as it does not exists anywhere but in memory. It simply does not exists on disk.